# Why is my Webpack ReactJS App so large?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have followed as many tips as I can find in packaging my Webpack ReactJS app for production. Unfortunately, the file size is still 3MB. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my Webpack Config file:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle-webpack.js',
    publicPath: './'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        screw_ie8: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: [ 'babel' ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
      },
      {test: /node_modules\/react-chatview/, loader: 'babel' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I use the following command to package it:

```
> NODE_ENV=production webpack -p
```

I get the following output:

```
bundle-webpack.js  3.1 MB       0  [emitted]  main
```

Best,

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that David L. Walsh was correct that I had too much development stuff in my app. However, the answer provided did not resolve the issue.

I resolved the issue using 3 steps.

1. Remove all the "hot-reloading" plugins from my webpack configuration, as David instructed.
2. Remove the hot reloading "react-transform" plugin from my .babelrc file.
3. Change the "devtool" parameter to "source-map" from "cheap-module-eval-source-map"

After following those steps, the final bundle file was 340kb while the source map was still 3MB. Fortunately, I don't have to include the source map in my application, so it can be downloaded at 340kb, which is still fairly large, but reasonable for modern browsers running on modern internet connections.

I would up-vote David's answer, but I don't have enough reputation points yet to do so.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you've still got a fair amount of dev stuff there, e.g. hot module replacement.

Take a look at webpack.config.prod.js at [React Transform Boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate) as a guide.

You may also be able to optimise your imports by including only the parts of the packages you need and leaving out the rest. See: [Reduce Your bundle.js File Size By Doing This One Thing](https://lacke.mn/reduce-your-bundle-js-file-size/) .

Comment: Thanks for the reply David! I followed the guides you gave me with no luck. Below is the output I get now.

    bundle-prod.js   349 kB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle-prod.js.map  3.13 MB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 629 hidden modules

I really can't understand what I'm missing. My app is a very simple ReactJS + Redux app.